# Extend Experience Profile Search with unique identifier

Tags: experience-profile

All of our contacts are identified by a unique customer id.
By default in the Experience Profile dashboard, we can search by name or e-mail.

**How can I extend this functionality so that the identifier gets searched too?**

[image]

SC version is 8.2 u2

Comment: Hey @Koen Heye- Looking for the same functionality. Have you been able to implement this. Any help appreciated

Comment: @VinodChavan Sorry but I don't recall anymore. If I find something, I'll update it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the contact search provider for the Experience Profile application.

It is defined in the **Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.config** as follows:

```
 <contactSearchProvider type="Sitecore.Cintel.ContactSearchProvider, Sitecore.Cintel" singleInstance="true" />
```

Code-wise it looks like you should copy-paste the disassembled code *(sadly)* in your implementation and customize the implementation of the `private SearchResults<IndexedContact> QueryIndex(IProviderSearchContext ctx, ContactSearchParameters parameters)` method.